# Select a relative result set as an array in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So here's my problem. I have 3 tables

[image]

`case_assign.cfid => case_fields.cfid and case_assign.uid => users.uid`.

The single query I am trying to write basically fetches all the cases between two dates while also selecting every person assigned to the case via the case_assign table and the case_assign table also fetches the names via the uid fields in both it and the users table.

Now here's the challenge. Since many people can be assigned to any one case, it will be fetching multiple rows from case_assign for a single row fetched from case_fields but the query isn't case_assign based, its case_fields based which means that I will get an error saying something like "mysql error: too many fields returned" or something like that.

So I am thinking, is there a way I can return the total number of rows selected for any one query gotten from the case_assign table into an array that will be sent to the client then I can probably json.parse() it on the client side.

Thanks

Comment: Does `GROUP_CONCAT(users.fname)` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cf.cfid, GROUP_CONCAT(u.fname) assignees
FROM case_fields cf
LEFT JOIN case_assign ca ON cf.cfid = ca.cfid
LEFT JOIN users u ON ca.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY cf.cfid
```

This will create a comma-separated list of user names in `assignees`. You can split this into an array in the client application.

Or you can use this query:

```
SELECT cf.cfid, u.fname
FROM case_fields cf
LEFT JOIN case_assign ca ON cf.cfid = ca.cfid
LEFT JOIN users u ON ca.uid = u.uid
ORDER BY cf.cfid
```

Then as you loop through the results, check if the current `cfid` is the same as the previous one; if it is, append `fname` to the assignee list, otherwise start a new entry in the result array.